# Mysqli nested prepared statement - retrieve error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a function which created an object which contains an array of objects.
However, when I have an error in my sql syntax, the error isn't shown.
When I change let's say book_images in my $queryGetImages to book_images_blabla, the prepare fails and the else is called.
There I throw an error, but first I have to close the $stmt object.
However. When I close this, the error isn't available anymore.
How is that possible? Because the error is thrown on the $stmtImages, not on the $stmt?

```
public function getBook($number){       
    $query = "select title from book where book_id = ?";
    if ($stmt = $this->database->getConnection()->prepare($query)) {            
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$number);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($title);     
        $stmt->store_result();          
        if(($stmt->num_rows) > 0){      
            $stmt->fetch(); 
            $book = new Book($title);
            //get images
            $queryGetImages = "select imageUrl from book_images where book_id = ?";                 
            if ($stmtImages = $this->database->getConnection()->prepare($queryGetImages)) {
                $stmtImages->bind_param('i',$number);
                $stmtImages->execute();
                $stmtImages->bind_result($imageUrl);        
                $stmtImages->store_result();                        
                if(($stmtImages->num_rows) > 0){
                    $images = array();
                    while($stmtImages->fetch()){
                        $image = new Image($imageUrl);
                        array_push($images,$image); 
                    }                               
                    $book->images = $images;                            
                }
                $stmtImages->close();
            }else{  
                echo $this->database->getConnection()->error; //this works
                $stmt->close();                     
                echo $this->database->getConnection()->error; //this doesn't                
                throw new Exception('Error: ' . $this->database->getConnection()->error;);
            }                                                   
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $book;
    }else{      
        throw new Exception('Error: ' . $this->database->getConnection()->error;);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use try catch throw rather than if else throw

Comment: I use the try catch in my mainpage where I call this function.  The if else is needed because you get a boolean value for the prepare check not an error.

Answer (score 0):

break your nest down and degub. make sure that individual query work first before you nest. you have no comma at //this doesn't 
and below an extra comma after error

why don't you do an join table

```
SELECT book.title, book_images.imageUrl FROM book
LEFT JOIN book_images
ON book.book_id=book_images.book_id WHERE book.book_id = ?;
```

Comment: The individual queries work, I didn't use a join because then you get repeated results when having multiple images. When I changed the table name in my inner statement to a non existing, It doesn't work anymore (which is correct behaviour) but the error is only printable if I don't close the main ($stmt) statement.

Comment: on this join add limit 1 if you want one image. you closed connection before second one and both are in the same else.

Comment: But I don't want one image, I want all of them...Anyway, I don't know what you mean with the connection is closed before the second one and both are in the same else, but the connection is never closed in this function, only the statement is closed. and in the inner else by closing the main statement, the error of the inner statement is gone.